# Is the above valid C code?

Tags: c

I was given this question in my college in a programming contest...

```
void duff(register char *to, register char *from, register int count)
  {
      register int n=(count+7)/8;
      switch(count%8){
      case 0: do{ *to++ = *from++;
      case 7:  *to++ = *from++;
      case 6: *to++ = *from++;
      case 5: *to++ = *from++;
      case 4: *to++ = *from++;
      case 3: *to++ = *from++;
      case 2: *to++ = *from++;
      case 1: *to++ = *from++;
              }while( --n >0);
      }
  }
```

Is the above valid C code? If so, what is it trying to acheive and why would anyone do something like the above?

Comment: @phresnel: [Good job asking](http://xkcd.com/233/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this C code do \[Duff's device\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723270/what-does-this-c-code-do-duffs-device)

Comment: I am sorry. I had seen this question on a puzzle site.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's known as Duff's device.

As far as I can remember it was written by someone doing special effects for a movie (Star Wars or something like that).  It was written this way to get maximum performance.

But, would I suggest to write code like this: NO.

Keep your code readable!